# In to navigate to the next to last page of a NavigationPage in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, navigation

I know there is a method `PopToRootAsync` for the NavigationPage class. It pops up and navigate to the first page. If let's say my navigation stack looks like the below diagram. I'm currently on PageN and I don't know how many pages are in the stack. How can I navigate to the next to last page (Page2 in below diagram)?

```
| +-----+ |
| |PageN| |
| +-----+ |
|    .    |
|    .    |
|    .    |
| +-----+ |
| |Page2| |
| +-----+ |
|         |
| +-----+ |
| |Page1| |
| +-----+ |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function I wrote a while back.

```
 public static async Task PopUntilDestination(Type DestinationPage, INavigation nav)
    {
        int LeastFoundIndex = 0;
        int PagesToRemove = 0;

        for (int index = MasterPageInstance.Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2; index > 0; index--)
        {
            if (MasterPageInstance.Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack[index].GetType().Equals(DestinationPage))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                LeastFoundIndex = index;
                PagesToRemove++;
            }
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < PagesToRemove; index++)
        {
            nav.RemovePage(MasterPageInstance.Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack[LeastFoundIndex]);
        }

        await nav.PopAsync();
    }
```

and to use it simply

```
PopUntilDestination(typeof(Page2), Navigation);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate the last second page, I suggest you can try the following code:

```
  Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[0]);
   Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
```

Removing the last navigation page, then pop to root page.